# Regular expressions - match tokens in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which represents a series of key presses and releases. In this schema, CTRL+C would be represented as:

`P CTRL P C R C R CTRL`

i.e., P for 'press' or 'R' for release plus some key name.
I want a regular expression which will extract all those tokens into an array:

`['P CTRL', 'P C', 'R C', 'R CTRL']`

How do I do it?

Comment: Is it pure string with whitespaces between the letters? Can you post an example of the actual string info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily if you use `(?=[PR] \w+)` to match the characters as a delimiter for a split. This will split the string between the commands.

This matches a space followed by a zero width (doesn't include the characters in the actual match) positive lookahead assertion. The lookahead is making sure that the space is followed by a P or an R and then a space and then one or more alphanumeric characters.

```js
const keys = 'P CTRL P C R C R CTRL'.split(/ (?=[PR] \w+)/);
console.log(keys);
//["P CTRL", "P C", "R C", "R CTRL"]
```

(note, at the time of writing, the stack snippets seem to be down.)